# NetBeans: Java: Shortcut for creating all cases in a switch

Tags: java, netbeans, switch-statement

Is there any shortcut to immediately create (for one enum) all cases in a switch case statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To keep the answer short: there's none (yet).

Feel free to file a [feature bug](https://netbeans.org/community/issues.html) at netbeans.

---

However, there are some helpers:

- **Case template:** Within the switch, type **`cs + <TAB>`** to generate a `case` template, including `break` and a ready-to-type case-value.
- **Switch/Case template:** Type **`sw + <TAB>`** to generate a switch/case template. It doesn't generate cases for all enum values, but in addition to the *case template* it reduces the effort a lot!

You can find all temples at: **`Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Code Templates`**.

Maybe you can write even a template to generate a switch/case for all enum values.

---

### Update

[**Feature announced for Netbeans 8.1**](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB81#Generate_missing_switch_clauses).